# How to change meteor router paths/slugs without reloading the template?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, slug

I have two router paths, one is /topic/:postId and one is /topic/:postId/:commentId. Both paths are pointing to the template "topic".

The first path opens the template with a list of all the post's comments. Whenever I select a comment, I filter some contents on the page based on the comment and I want the route to change to the second path (allowing users to copy the link to this filtered page directly), but I want meteor to stay on the same template and not reload the page.

In short, how can I change the URL/slugs without reloading the page?

**Edit:** These are my routes pointing to the same template and I'd like to jump between them without (noticeable) reload. I left out waitOn and multiple data lines for simplicity' sake:

```
Router.route("/topic/:postId", {
    name: "Topic",
    data: function () {
            return {
                content: "topic",
                post: this.params.postId
            };
        }
});

Router.route("/topic/:postId/:commentId", {
    name: "Comment",
    data: function () {
            return {
                content: "topic",
                post: this.params.postId,
                comment: this.params.commentId
            };
        }
});
```

Comment: can't you just use a `#` in the URL to skip to the anchor of the comment? That's the typical way of doing this and it doesn't change the actual URL, so the page doesn't reload.

Comment: But I need it to change the actual URL. Because I want users to be able to copy that URL and share it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'd prefer it to do nothing else than to change the URL to contain the ID of my selected comment.

Comment: You may not understand exactly what the # does. The URL that the user sees and can bookmark and share *will* change, when you add the # segment. But to the browser it is a no-op, it won't load another page, because it knows that the page the URL refers to is still the same (just the location on the page has changed).

Comment: I googled it for a while and figured it out. It's absolutely perfect and does exactly what I needed! Thank you! If you submit an answer I'll accept it.